# cPickle vs dill - python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, dill

As i couldn't fine the setup pf cPickle i'm using dill. In documentation they said both are same, but in dill there is no option like dump and all which is being provided by cPickle or Pickle. is there any link where i can download the cPickle or Pickle ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the author of `dill`.

`pickle` and `cPickle` come in the python standard library.  All you have to do is import them, and there they are.  If you have python, you should have `pickle` and `cPickle` already… If you were instead using python 3.x, then there is no `cPickle`… it's been merged with `pickle`.

`dill` has a `dump` as well as a `dumps`.  See the source here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/dill.py#L121